# Can't apply "sale rule" in cart without reload page

Tags: cart, rules, sale-price

How I can determine what "sales rules" is applied after changing set of items in cart without reloading page. Tried something like this, but correct rules applied after reloading page. Magento 1.9.0.1

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$quote = $cart->getQuote();

$quote->removeAllItems();

$quote->addProduct($product, 1);

$quote->collectTotals();

$quote->save();

$cart->save();

$cart->init();

$quote = $cart->getQuote();

$quote->collectTotals();

if($quote->getAppliedRuleIds())

foreach (explode(',',$quote->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId) {

    $rules[] = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->getItemById($ruleId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :

```
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsetAll();
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quote->addProduct($product, 1);

    $quote->collectTotals();

    if($quote->getAppliedRuleIds())
        foreach (explode(',',$quote->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId) {
            $rules[] = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->getItemById($ruleId);
        }
```